# Error faced during install moodle

Tags: moodle

I am a beginner in moodle. I download moodle 2.9.4+ version. Then I extract file from the zip file and execute the application start moodle. It starts running properly, but when I enter the IP address 127.0.0.1 in my browser it shows an error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. To resolve the problem I have repeatedly cleared the browsing data from the chrome, but the problem is same. It is redirected to wampserver localhost. This problem is same even after uninstalling and removing wamp server from my computer.Please help me out of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming / deleting the cache folder in the moodledata folder.

See : https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=230067